# How to place 3d box inside another 3d box using three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am working on **cargo management** project.   I need to render the packing order in 3d image,  I am beginner to use **THREE.js**.
I have the positions (x,y,z axis) and size of the objects inside the container and container size.  Now I need to render in 3d image.

I learned to render the container and objects separately, but don't know how to place the objects inside the container.

Please help me out to learn how to do this.

Here I tried something out like this.

```
       init();
       animate();

         function init() {

            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 6000);
            camera.position.x = radius * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));
            camera.position.y = radius * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));
            camera.position.z = radius * Math.cos(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));
            scene.add(camera);

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(2000, 2150, 5600, 1, 1, 1);               
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x000000, wireframe:true });

            container = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            container.position.x = 100;
            container.position.y = 100;
            container.position.z = 100;
            container.scale.x = 2000;
            container.scale.y = 2150;
            container.scale.z = 5600;
            scene.add(container);
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff }));
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                object.scale.x = Math.random() + 5;
                object.scale.y = Math.random() + 5;
                object.scale.z = Math.random() + 5;
                scene.add(object);
                container.add(object);
            }
        }

        function animate()
        {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

But it shows no result and no error.

Comment: Please add a full working example to your post and specify a concret problem. At the moment your question is "too broad".

Comment: Thank you @reporter for showing interest to answer my question, below code worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the objects as the child of the container and then set the position of the objects.

```
// first add the container in the scene
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(container_width, container_height, container_depth);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
var container = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(container);

// then add objects as the child of container
var geometry_obj = new THREE.BoxGeometry(object_width, object_height, object_depth);
var material_obj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry_obj, material_obj);
// you can set the object's position in the container
object.position.set(object_position.x, object_position.y, object_position.z)
container.add(object);
```

Comment: It shows the 
"three.js:10801 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. " error occurs when executing container.add(object);

Comment: Thank you @Razsheduzzaman Sourov this thing worked for me. earlier i made mistakes in camera and added material_obj in scene and also in container. when i correct it then things went right.